# Parse parameterized .exe with variables out of PowerShell in a new cmd window

Tags: winforms, powershell

I wrote a PowerShell GUI for a parameterized .exe file.
The .exe needs to be run with 2 parameters, a slected file and a report format.
I've built my event like that:

```cs
$VBVGUIValidateButton.Add_Click({
    if ($Global:SelectedFile -eq $Null) {
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("No File Selected. Please select a file !", "Error", 0, [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Exclamation)
    } else {
        if ($VBVGUIXMLReport.Checked -eq "True") {
            Choose-Folder
            #$ReportString = "$ReportLocation" + "$ReportName" + ".xml"
            $ReportString = "$Global:SelectedFolder" + "\" + "$ReportName" + ".xml"
            Set-Location -Path $ValidatorPath
            .\TOOL.exe /file:$Global:SelectedFile /report:$ReportString /format:xml
            [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Validation process finished !" , "Information", 0, [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Information)
        } else {
            Choose-Folder
            #$ReportString = "$ReportLocation" + "$ReportName" + ".html"
            $ReportString = "$Global:SelectedFolder" + "\" + "$ReportName" + ".html"
            Set-Location -Path $ValidatorPath
            .\TOOL.exe /file:$Global:SelectedFile /report:$ReportString
            [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Validation process finished !" , "Information", 0, [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Information)
        }
    }
})
```

What I especially want is opening/parsing the .exe file in a new CMD window, so the process of the `TOOL.exe` can be seen.

This part here:

```cs
Choose-Folder
#$ReportString = "$ReportLocation" + "$ReportName" + ".html"
$ReportString = "$Global:SelectedFolder" + "\" + "$ReportName" + ".html"
Set-Location -Path $ValidatorPath
.\TOOL.exe /file:$Global:SelectedFile /report:$ReportString
[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Validation process finished !" , "Information", 0, [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Information)
```

The `TOOL.exe` writes information out in the CMD if it's exectued directly. If I execute it via my PowerShell GUI, the GUI "freezes" (obvious as it is working in the background) and I cannot see the progress. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Try to google about responsive Powershell GUI. There's a lot examples available.

Comment: Ok i did, but i don't understand if this helps me here. Read about progress bars and so on. But the tool iam trying to bring into cmd, is native writing into cmd once executed. I just want the Event handler after clicking to bring up the cmd and execute my command stated above. Thanks for the hint, though !

Comment: The issue in your case is the same as with the progress bar: your GUI is not processing Windows events when the tool is running. Therefore the tool should be run in background.